# App like Instacart for ordering handyman repair services?

Tags: repair

If there is already an app out there that helps people order simple home repair services, can someone please let me know?  I'm really tired of browsing my printed yellow book and calling out of date numbers.   My needs are pretty basic:

- read and compare reviews
- pay online via a trusted middleman platform (like instacart or airbnb)
- book a time slot online

Thanks.

Comment: There are 20 or 30 websites that do this.  At least two of which advertise on TV ad nauseam. Why not use them?

Comment: TaskRabbit may work for you.

Comment: Thanks, David.  I tried TaskRabbit actually, it's very close to the app structure I'm thinking of.  Unfortunately, the work I need done usually requires more "expertise/skill"  than the simpler ones offered on TaskRabbit.  I'm looking for an app that has services offered by professionals like electricians, plumbers, painters, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Chenmunka.  Can you please give me a couple of website examples?   Are there any that perhaps you had tried before and would recommend? I don't really watch TV often, I feel like there must be famous sites that I have never heard of.  I did Google and tried one of the top search result websites.  This website asked me to upload photos of the work I needed done even before allowing searching/browsing of available services.   I would prefer an app that allows users to browse available options before providing personal details if you know what I mean.